# Problem 25 (c) Kosniowski. A subset homeomorphic to the open disc is not a open neighbourhood of any of its points.

Tags: algebraic-topology

25.1 (c) Prove that if a subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homeomorphic to the open disc $\mathring{D}^2$ then $W$ is not an open neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of any of its points .
Hint: If $W$ is an open neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $w\in W$ then there is a subset $U_1\subseteq W$ with $w\in U_1$ and $U_1\cong \mathring{D}^3$ y definition.

Hi. I cannot understand this problem. It corresponds to the section on fundamental groups.
The idea I have is to calculate the fundamental group of $W$ which is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the open disk $\mathring{D}^2$ and also calculate the fundamental group of $U_1$ which is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $\mathring{D}^3$ and then obtain a contradiction but I don't know if it is a good way.

Assuming the hint. What would be the idea of ​​contradiction? (I ask to try to prove it)

Actualization 1. Assuming the hint. I have the following idea:

exists $\phi:U_1\to\mathring{D}^3$  homeomorphism

exists $\psi:W\to\mathring{D}^2$ homeomorphism then $\left.\psi\right|_{U_1}:U_1\to \psi(U_1)$ is a homeomorphism.

Now, $\left.\psi\right|_{U_1}\circ\phi^{-1}:\mathring{D}^3\to \psi(U_1)\subset \mathring{D}^2$ is a homeomorphism and I don't know how to conclude anymore

Comment: $D^n$ are contractible so assuming there is a homeomorphism between $\pi_1(D^2)$ and $\pi_1(D^3)$ gives you one between trivial groups. I would suggest trying to restrict to a punctured domain since they might have interesting fundamental groups. Are $\pi_1(D^2 \setminus \{0\})$ and $\pi_1(D^3 \setminus \{0\})$ isomorphic?

Comment: The fundamental group of the punctured disk is different from the fundamental group of the punctured sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Daniel Apsley's interesting comment, we may consider the following.

Suppose $\phi:W\to B^2$ is the homeomorphism, then $\phi|_{U_1-\{w\}}$ is a homeomoprhism, too. By the assumption (the hint), $\phi(U_1)\approx B^3$, so $\pi_1(\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\}))\cong\pi_1(B^3-\{0\})\cong\{1\}\implies$ simply connected.

On the other hand, we have $\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\})\subset B^2\subset\Bbb{R}^2$. This space cannot be simply connected (if you've seen a proof, then this is immediate)
If $\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\})$ were simply connected, then every map $f:S^1\to \phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\})$ can be extended to $\tilde{f}:D^2\to\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\})$, so it suffices to find one counterexample to this statement. Actually, there is a simple and natural one, just have a try before revealing the spoiler. ;)

> Consider the map \begin{align}f:S^1\to\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\}),\\ \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \phi(w)+\begin{pmatrix}\epsilon\cos(\theta)\\\epsilon\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\end{align} where $\epsilon$ is carefully chosen so that the radius fits in the target space. Then, one may notice that there exists another map \begin{align}f^{-1}:y\mapsto \dfrac{y-\phi(w)}{||y-\phi(w)||}\end{align} that acts as an inverse since $(f^{-1}\circ f)(x)=x$ by direct computation. Then, the continuous map $f^{-1}\circ \tilde{f}$ induces $f^{-1}_*\circ\tilde{f}_*$, which $\twoheadrightarrow$. But this is impossible because $f^{-1}_*\circ\tilde{f}_*:\pi_1(D^2)\to\pi_1(S^1)\not\cong\{1\}$.

Comment: Actually there are some related questions that discuss the similar problem......(I just noticed that)

Comment: What is that $\twoheadrightarrow$?

The contradiction is because $\pi_1(D^2)\cong \pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ but $\pi_1(D^2)=\left\{1\right\}$?

Comment: @eraldcoil $\twoheadrightarrow$ means surjection. The map $f^{-1}\circ\tilde{f}$ satisfies the criterion of retraction, so it induces surjection on the fundamental group, but $\pi_1(D_2)\cong\{1\}$ CANNOT surjects onto $\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb{Z}$. So we have a contradiction. :)

Comment: @eraldcoil Feel free to ask other questions regarding my answer...

Comment: $(f^{-1}\circ \tilde{f})_{*}:\pi_1(D^2)\to\pi_1(S^1)$ continuous and surjertive implies that $\pi_1(D^2)\simeq \pi(S^1)$?

Comment: @eraldcoil I've clearly stated that $\{1\}\cong\pi_1(D^2)\not\cong\pi_1(S^1)\cong\Bbb{Z}$. It is clear that they DON'T have isomorphic fundamental groups, and moreover, the homomorphism from the trivial group $\pi_1(D^2)$ CANNOT surject onto $\pi_1(S^1)$ because the fundamental group of a disk is trivial whereas the fundamental group of a circle is non-trivial... I didn't mention anything about these two groups being isomorphic.

Comment: @eraldcoil I'll try to be clearer. $f^{-1}\circ \tilde{f}:\pi_1(D^2)\to\pi_1(S^1)$ becomes surjective by our assumption that $\phi(U_1)-\phi(\{w\})$ is simply connected. However, $\pi_1(D^2)$ is trivial, whereas $\pi_1(S^1)$ is not, so the map $f^{-1}\circ \tilde{f}$ cannot be surjective. And this is the contradiction. There's nothing about isomorphism, and there's no evidence for us to deduce the isomorphism.